# How to build as an ia32 solution from visual studio using cmake

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake, compilation, cpu-architecture

I have a module project using `cmake` with the following configuration:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13)
project(app)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

add_library(app MODULE src/library.cpp src/library.h)
```

Once solution generated using `cmake .. -G "Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release`, I can find an `app.sln` solution.

I open it with `Visual Studio 2019` and click on the button `Local Windows Debugger`.  I can see also a drop-down menu containing the value `x64` and an item `Configuration Manager`.

Why isn't there an `ia32` or `x86` option by default? I just can't create a new configuration since the configuration is totally non user friendly.

Anyone has an idea for compile the library for target `32 bits` programs?

**EDIT**

---

I now compile using `cmake .. -G "Visual Studio 16 2019" -DCMAKE_GENERATOR_PLATFORM=x86 -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release` and the project couldn't be even loaded (cuz of some missing configuration on visual studio, that's what the IDE say)

Comment: What does the command line `cmake .. -G "Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release` do? I would think it does a `x64` compile targeting the Visual Studio 2015 compatible compiler output. https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/generator/Visual%20Studio%2015%202017.html So why would you be surprised that you can't debug it with x86?

Comment: I recently changed to the latest visual studio 16 2019, (removing Win64) and it's still the same, I could not find anything related to 32 bit arch target

Comment: I tried using `set(CMAKE_VS_PLATFORM_TOOLSET_HOST_ARCHITECTURE x86)` but nothing happens :/

Comment: It appears from the VS 2019 version of the `cmake` documentation, https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/generator/Visual%20Studio%2016%202019.html , that you should only need to specify `cmake -G "Visual Studio 16 2019" -A Win32` and I would keep things as simple as possible and let `cmake` do its job. Not sure what you mean by "nothing happens" in your last comment. Surely something happened however what happened is not what you expected or wanted.

Comment: it was indeed -A Win32 and associated with -Thost=x86. Now working thanks

Comment: I have put my comment into an answer to your post so that your post will now show as having an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears from the VS 2019 version of the [cmake documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/generator/Visual%20Studio%2016%202019.html) that you should only need to specify:

```
 cmake -G "Visual Studio 16 2019" -A Win32
```

and I would keep things as simple as possible and let `cmake` do its job.

Not sure what you mean by "nothing happens" in your last comment. Surely something happened however what happened is not what you expected or wanted.