# How to build 32-bit VS projects using CMAKE for AWS SDK on 64-bit Windows

Tags: windows, visual-studio, amazon-web-services, cmake, x86

I downloaded the Amazon AWS SDK (master.zip) and extracted it to C:\aws-sdk-cpp-master.  I installed CMAKE 3.17.2, and I'm running 64-bit Windows 10 with Visual Studio 2019 previously installed.

I created C:\aws-sdk-cpp-master\build and set that as my current directory.  Then I ran:

`cmake .. -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release`

Having never used CMAKE before, I didn't know what to expect.  It generated 64-bit projects, and Visual Studio was able to open them.  However, I need 32-bit projects to be able to integrate AWS with pre-existing projects, so then I tried creating a "build32" subfolder.  I moved to that and then ran:

`cmake .. -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -D CMAKE_GENERATOR_PLATFORM=x86`

It started running but then failed with this:

```
    Build started 5/12/2020 9:39:49 AM.
    Project "C:\aws-sdk-cpp-master\build32\.deps\CMakeFiles\3.17.2\VCTargetsPath.vcxproj" on node 1 (default targets).
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets(376,5): error MSB8013: This project doesn't contain the Configuration and Platform combination of Debug|Win32. [C:\aws-sdk-cpp-master\build32\.deps\CMakeFiles\3.17.2\VCTargetsPath.vcxproj]
    Done Building Project "C:\aws-sdk-cpp-master\build32\.deps\CMakeFiles\3.17.2\VCTargetsPath.vcxproj" (default targets) -- FAILED.
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
    Build FAILED.
    "C:\aws-sdk-cpp-master\build32\.deps\CMakeFiles\3.17.2\VCTargetsPath.vcxproj" (default target) (1) ->
    (PrepareForBuild target) ->
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets(376,5): error MSB8013: This project doesn't contain the Configuration and Platform combination of Debug|Win32. [C:\aws-sdk-cpp-master\build32\.deps\CMakeFiles\3.17.2\VCTargetsPath.vcxproj]
        0 Warning(s)
        1 Error(s)
```

I haven't been able to find anything specific about building the projects for 32-bit Windows (but running on 64-bit Windows).  Is this supported?  Do I need different command line options?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried as shown in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58252285/3987854) response? You might also try running these commands from a 32-bit version of the Visual Studio Developer Command Prompt.

Comment: Yes, that was it!  This is the command I want:
cmake .. -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -A Win32
Thank you!